# Override Generic Controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I have the following function in my abstract controller

```
public abstract class GenericController<T extends PersistentObject> {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/validation.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationResponse ajaxValidation(@Valid T t, BindingResult result) {
        ValidationResponse res = new ValidationResponse();
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            res.setStatus("SUCCESS");
        } else {
            res.setStatus("FAIL");
            List<FieldError> allErrors = result.getFieldErrors();
            List<ErrorMessage> errorMesages = new ArrayList<ErrorMessage>();
            for (FieldError objectError : allErrors) {
                errorMesages.add(new ErrorMessage(objectError.getField(),
                        objectError.getDefaultMessage()));
            }
            res.setErrorMessageList(errorMesages);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

At most cases the validation is sufficient for different kind of entities. Now I would like to customize the validation on my concrete controller as

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UserController extends GenericController<User> {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/validation.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationResponse ajaxValidation(@Valid User user,
            BindingResult result, Locale locale) {
        ValidationResponse res = super.ajaxValidation(user, result);
        if (!user.getPassword().equals(user.getConfirmPassword())) {
            res.setStatus("FAIL");
            res.getErrorMessageList().add(
                    new ErrorMessage("confirmPassword", messageSource
                            .getMessage("password.mismatch", null, locale)));
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

With this I get the following error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'userController' bean method`. How can I solve this issue ? Is there a better approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that after extending your generic controller you have two ***different*** methods

```
public ValidationResponse ajaxValidation(@Valid T t, BindingResult result)
```

and

```
public ValidationResponse ajaxValidation(@Valid User user,
        BindingResult result, Locale locale)
```

with the exact same mapping

> user/validation.json

An ugly solution would be to add the `Locale locale` param to your abstract controller method (even if you don't use it) and add the `@Overwrite` annotation to the UserController method (you'll get a compilation error otherwise). This way the two methods become one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference, I totally missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The generic controller is extended by other classes ?  Then you will have two identical requestmappings.

Are you sure the UserController is correctly getting user prepend request mapping applied ? As this works :

```
@RequestMapping("test")
public class ExampleController extends AbstractController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/Home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHome(Model model) {
        return "home";
    }
```

with the same mapping in AbstractController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHome(Model model) {
        return "home";
    }
```

Comment: My idea was to extend the generic controller class so I can reuse the piece of code. Yes the UserController is annotated with both @Controller and @RequestMapping("user").

Comment: your idea is correct ... this works. So there must be someting wrong with your implementation

Comment: I get the exception during the context initialization. Which area of implementation I should check ?